# ActionMailer adding cc and bcc as an option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

how do you send a mail with having cc and bcc as an option only

```
data[:cc] = cc if cc.present?
data[:bcc] = cc if bcc.present?

mail to: to, subject: subject, data
```

This one renders an error

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
  def welcome(recipient)
    @account = recipient
    mail(to: recipient.email_address_with_name,
         bcc: ["bcc@example.com", "Order Watcher <watcher@example.com>"])
  end
```

You do not need any `:cc` tag. And all the recepients in `to` except current recepient will be seen as CC:
`to: ["admin@corsego.com", "user@corsego.com"]`

In your particular case:

```
to = ["admin@corsego.com", "user@corsego.com"]
bcc = ["bcc@corsego.com", "secret@corsego.com"]
mail to: to, bcc: bcc, subject: subject, data
```

Read the Docs [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)